# Why is the collect-phrases cli command not working at all?

Tags: magento2.1.6

According to the Magento [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html), I should be able to create a translation csv file by calling `bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases` command. I have tried all variations of the following

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "path/to/my/file.csv" -m
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "path/to/my/file.csv" path/to/my/module
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="path/to/my/file.csv" "path/to/my/module"
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="path/to/my/file.csv" --magento
```

But I always get the same error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                
Directory path is needed when --magento flag is not set. 

i18n:collect-phrases [-o|--output="..."] [-m|--magento] [directory]
```

I feel like the documentation is totally wrong, or the command is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it has been fully tested -:

> php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/i18n/en_US.csv" "app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/"

You should see the following message

> Dictionary successfully processed.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "path/to/my/file.csv" -m "path/to/my/module"
```

Comment: I tried that one also and I am still getting the same error. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the paths, it just is not liking the command for some reason.